# Place Order leads to 'Unable to place Order, Please Try Again' with Paypal Payflow Payment Method in magento 2

Tags: php, paypal, magento2

#### Preconditions

1) Magento 2.1.1

2) Set Payment Method in Stores->Configuration->Sales->Payment Methods->**Paypal** Payflow Pro (Includes Express Checkout)

Give all required configuration information like Email, Partner etc.

#### Steps to reproduce

1) Add Configurable product in cart

2) Go to Checkout page

3) Login with email and password

4) Provide Shipping information and choose free shipping method

5) Choose credit card payment method

6) Then click place order

#### Expected result

Need to go order success page

#### Actual result

I got this error above Payment Method step

'Unable to place Order, Please Try Again'

Page loads for few secs and stops.When I debug error in the console I got these responses.

1) http://localhost/rest/default_migrated/V1/carts/mine/set-payment-information

Response : True

2) http://localhost/paypal/transparent/requestSecureToken/

{"payflowpro":{"fields":{"result":"0","securetoken":"XXXXXXX","securetokenid":"YYYYYYYY"
,"respmsg":"Approved","result_code":"0"}},"success":true,"error":false}

3) https://payflowlink.paypal.com/

**Reload the page to get source for: https://payflowlink.paypal.com/**

Please check this error and help me how to resolve this paypal error.